# Facebook Turn based Match making

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

Hello I have couple of questions about turn-based matchmaking with the facebook.

1) From [FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/#match)

> Requests can be sent to any player that has already installed the game; the sender and recipient do not need to be friends.

So how can I send request to random recipient who is not friend of current player (I men I do not know his id) Or I have to keep players id's on my web server and then request random player id from the web server?

Reading the request. The reading documentation is not clear enough. It shows how can I read current user app request (turn request for example) and specify fields I need. But how do I can read app request form current user only for my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to keep player IDs on your server, and of course only send requests to people who are using your App too.

How to read requests is explained in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2#reading

If you scroll down to "Reading all requests":

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?access_token=[USER ACCESS TOKEN]
```

Comment: Yea, I know, As you see in my question I sad that documentation shows how to read the request, and it's pretty understandable. Point is I want to read requests sanded by my app only. Currently requests contains data about application '"application": {
        "name": "APP_NAME", 
        "id": "APP_ID"
      }, '   So for me it look like I need to filter requests array after loading to keep requests related to my app only. So I was wondering is it possible to read request only for my app?

Comment: i am not sure what you want to achieve, to be honest. isn´t that what the api call is for? the one i posted in my answer? you want "requests sended by your app", that´s exactly what you get with the call. if you want to get a list of ALL requests of the app (not just user), you may need to store all requests on your own.

Comment: Okay got it, I was confused since apprequest notification object contains info about app. So it was looks like I am able to read user notification from other apps as well. Thanks for your time and help. By the way can you suggest documentation / tutorial about facebook turn-based matchmaking, so far I only saw request with ***action_type = turn*** also I see ***data*** field which can be used for transferring move data, but not sure how to pass turns from one user to another and how to notify player about match result.

Comment: there is no direct facebook implementation for this, you should program that on your own and send app notifications or app requests to tell users about their move.